# jQuery: CSS Selector: How to select all elements except a specific class?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I need to select the contents of div#request but not the content of .requestHeader. Which selector should I use?

```
<div id="request">
  <h3 class="requestHeader">
    Request Details
  </h3>
    Dear Human, In this life you're allowed to make only one request. Keep in mind! Even that request will never be resolved!!
    <br/>
      Request for Money&nbsp;
      75.00&nbsp;
      USD&nbsp;
      per day
</div>
```

I tried `div#request:not(.requestHeader)`. It isn't working and gives the same result as `div#request`. What am I missing?

Desired Output: (just to print)

```
    Dear Human, In this life you're allowed to make only one request. Keep in mind! Even that request will never be resolved!!
    <br/>
      Request for Money&nbsp;
      75.00&nbsp;
      USD&nbsp;
      per day
```

I need to do this without chaining. i.e. `$('#request'):not('requestHeader')` just no can do. I just have freedom to do just this `$('SELECTOR-HERE')`

Comment: There must be only one element with ID `request`. In your example, the element with ID request doesn't have any class names, so `#request:not(.requestHeader)` selects the same element. In your example, which elements have to be selected?

Comment: can you create  a fiddle

Comment: `.requestHeader` is inside `#request` which changes things. What is your desired end result? For example: Do you want to change the text of something?

Comment: @RobW I am just printing it as output.

Comment: jQuery selectors are not the same thing as CSS selectors. In fact, this is not possible with a pure CSS selector but it *may be* possible with jQuery's selector extensions.

Answer (score 6):

```
$('*','#request').not(".requestHeader")
```

Finds all elements inside the `#request` elements, and then excludes elements with the class `.requestHeader`

The problem you're having is probably that there are no other elements inside the `#request` div, the text is just textnodes and not elements, so to select the contents of the targeting div as well you probably need to use `andSelf()` and maybe `contents()` depending on how you intend to use the selector, and that's the key part needed for answering the question, do you intend to just replace the text or interact with it as a DOM element etc.

Comment: Can't chain what functions? Are you trying to change a color or replace part of the text etc. There would be different approaches as to what you intend to do as you can't just select the textnode and chain it.

Comment: I am just scraping the data from a page. The scraper lets me use selector but not chaining.

Comment: @San The following selector does the same thing as the chained function in this answer: `#request :not(.requestHeader)` (notice the space between `#request` and `:not`).

Comment: @RobW But it doesn't select anything at all :-(

Comment: @San It does select the `<br>` **element**. Did you want to select the **text nodes** instead? Then use [`.contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), and filter the collection.

Comment: @RobW - actually, it's not the same, this one uses the asterix to find all elements in the context of #request, but that's really not important, San is trying to select textnodes within the element and exclude elements with a certain class, the question is just what he would like to do with the text, change it out with something else, or just target it for something, or get the text itself to run some sort of check etc. I already mentioned contents() to get the textnode, but if just trying to change a color or something like that there are other ways to target the text within an element.

Comment: @adeneo The selectors are exactely equal. `*` selects all elements. `*:not(.foo)` selects all elements which do not have class foo. `:not(.foo)` selects all ... which does not have class foo. Wait, only elements are selected, so `...` = elements, and `*:not(.foo)` is equal to `:not(.foo)`.

Comment: @RobW - I see, did'nt notice the space there :) it's in the line-break, anyway it's probably not what San is after, and I don't get why it can't be chained either?

Comment: @adeneo I interpreted the OPs comment as "I have a dumb stubborn tool which accepts jQuery selectors only". If I'm correct, then the OP either has to modify the tool, or add a new jQuery selector which implements `.contents()`.

Comment: @RobW Exactly, this tool accepts jQuery selectors only and I have no authority over it. So, I just need a jQuery selector which does the above along with the `.contents()`

Comment: @San Afaik, such one does not exist yet. You say that you don't have control over the tool. But are you allowed to extend the jQuery object?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#request').not('.requestHeader')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can change the HTML I would suggest putting a span element around the text. This will allow you to select everything but the requestHeader class easily.

See this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/davew9999/gepga/

Comment: No, I don't have the control over the HTML

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see is to filter the contents of the wrapping element for text nodes.

```
var theText = $('#request').contents().filter(function() {
     // Text nodes only
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).text();

// Trim leading and trailing white spaces
console.log($.trim(theText));
```

See JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YNLwG/1/

Answer (score 0):

This jQuery will be applied to all elements within the #request element except the element with .requestHeader class.

```
$("#request *:not('.requestHeader')");
```